# Graphite: sumSeries function not working

Tags: python, metrics, graphite, grafana

I am struck in a problem:

I am sending data via command line using this command in every 1 second.

```
set -x; while true; do echo "System.monitoring.notification.like.1.failure $((RANDOM%1+1)) date +%s" | nc 127.0.0.1 2003; sleep 1; done
```

My data is going to graphite and metric is also created but still when I try to use `sumSeries` function on this data but its not returning me the total count as expected.

```
sumSeries(System.monitoring.notification.like.1.failure)
```

Can you please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sumSeries(System.monitoring.notification.like.1.failure)` will not return total count, and that's expected. Please see its [documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.sumSeries):

"This will add metrics together and return the sum at each datapoint. (See integral for a sum over time)".

So, probably you're looking for [integral()](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.integral) instead - or even more probable, [summarize()](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize).

Comment: I am sending this data per second using command line, but its still not working. Can you help me out in this.

noti.system.demo.success 1 1495094521 | nc  127.0.0.1 2003
noti.system.demo.failure 1 1495094521 | nc  127.0.0.1 2003

Comment: Could you please elaborate what's exactly not working? I.e. what you're doing, what's you expecting and what's happening instead. Thanks!